# Why is ofstream::write adding extra bytes to the end of file?

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, hex

I'm trying to write the following bytes to a file

```
[03 00 01 00 FF 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 FF]
```

but I keep getting the following bytes added to the end

```
[03 01 0F C0 00 08 00 A0 00 C7 00 00 00 02 00 70 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00]
```

I've read up, and I've been told to use `std::ios::binary` when opening the file, which doesn't seem to help.
Here's my code

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int height = 1,
        length = 3;
    int data[] = {
        0x3,0x0,0x1,0x0,
        0xff, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x0, 0xff, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0, 0xff
    };

    ofstream file("thing.dki", std::ios::binary);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++) {
        file.write((char*) &data[i], 1);
    }
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you hoping to write bytes or ints?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm writing the bytes fine, my problem is the extra ones being generated

Comment: Your problem is you've made an array of ints, not unsigned chars (bytes). Try printing out what `sizeof(data)` is versus the actual number of items in your array and you'll see the problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja ah, thank you, I changed it to an array of unsigned chars and it works flawlessly now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
using byte = unsigned char;
```

to the top of you code and then replace

```
int data[]
```

with

```
byte data[]
```

the issue is you have already addressed this as integer data which can have varying size based on your OS architecture and trailing zeros, but if you use char instead it is automatically allocated lowest possible memory space.